A question about cosets
I can't understand the following statement very well:
Let $G$ be a group and $H \subseteq G$ a subgroup. Then:
$$ \forall g_1,g \in G :\ \ (gg_1)H=g(g_1H):=\{gg_2| g_2\in g_1H\} $$
This basically means that the coset of $(gg_1)$ on $H$ is the same as the coset of $g$ on the coset $g_1H$. However by the definition of the coset we have to have an element of $G$ - $g'$ and a subgroup $H'\subseteq G$ performing action on $G$ and the coset is the orbit of $g'$. However in the statement we have the coset $g_1H$ playing the role of a subroup but I can see that this coset won't be a subgroup for every $g'$ . $\exists g'\in G:g'H\nsubseteq G$ . Am I correct that not every coset is a subgroup? After all if we have more than one cosets the identity element must be in only one of them.

You're right: of all the cosets of a subgroup $H$, only $H$ itself is a subgroup of G, because the other cosets don't contain the identity. In this case, the statement doesn't say that $g_1 H$ is a subgroup and that we can take cosets of it, but it defines the notation $g(g_1 H)$ (and states that it is equal to the coset $(gg_1)H$).

It is worth noting that for an arbitrary subset $A \subseteq G$ and element $g \in G$ it is common to define $gA$ as ${ g \cdot a : a \in A }$. Also for $A, B \subseteq G$, $AB$ is defined as ${ a \cdot b : a \in A, b \in B }$ etc.
